# How can I differentiate between two docked applications existing on Mac OS X's dock?

Tags: macos, shortcuts, dock

I have the different versions of the same application added several times in the dock but the application icon and title is identical.

I cannot change the icon or the file name because they are recreated each time I rebuild.

OS X is displaying only the application name as a tooltip not the path and I want to be able to start each of these flavours of that application (like debug, release,...). On Windows it is very easy because you can change the shortcut icon or see the tooltip.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you command-click an application icon in the Dock, the Finder will show you the actual application file rather than opening it.

Answer (score 2):

"Tooltip" isn't really the right word for what you mention. The Dock's functionality is to specifically display the icon and name exactly as it would be in the Finder. It sounds like you're going to be rebuilding often and don't want to have to change an icon or executable name every time you rebuild.

What I think might work the best for what you're trying to accomplish is to write some quick AppleScripts to simply act as app launchers. Give them easily distinguishable icons and names, and leave them in your dock—then just point them at the locations of where your different builds will appear.

Answer (score 0):

- Quit all running apps
- Throw out all the icons from the Dock for the app that you are having problems with
- Find the version of the app that you actually want to use
- Drag it to the Dock
- [Optional] Find other/older versions of the app that are no longer needed and delete them

Comment: Probably you did not understand, I want all of them on the launcher.

Comment: @Sorin: thanks for clarifying - I suggest you add this requirement to your question for the benefit of anyone else who might want to help.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to change the icons of applications. This may help to visually distinguish between the apps.

There are multiple ways to do this such as [using Finder's `Get Info` inspector](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Mac-OS-X-Icons). Be sure to remove then re-add the app from the Dock for it to refresh the icon.